# What is the proper way to disallow an invalid WPF DependencyProperty change?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

My custom control shows an image.  It has event handlers that allow the user to pan/drag the image and zoom it in or out.  It exposes two `DependencyProperties`

- `ImageCenter` - The current center point of the control in Image coordinates
- `ImageRect` - The current bounds of the control in Image coordinates

The client is allowed to bind to both of these properties simultaneously, but if they do, at least one of those bindings MUST use `BindingMode.OneWayToSource`.  So you can force the view to show the image centered on a certain coordinate (without changing zoom) or you can force the view to show a specific `Rect` of the image (so changing zoom and panning at the same time) but you cannot do both.

(This reminds me a bit of how you may bind `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` or explicitly set its children in XAML but you may not do both.  This is still more complicated behavior than I would like but for now I feel I need it.)

Given this requirement, what is the proper protocol to disallow a violation of the binding rule?

- I assume I need to check the binding in `PropertyChangedCallback` function for each property, is that correct?  I would prefer to do so less frequently but I do not see any sort of `BindingSet` or `BindingCleared` event that I can hook on to.   And the `ValidateValueCallback` signature won't permit this sort of check.
- When I detect an invalid situation, what is the proper thing to do?  Throw an exception?

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageCenterProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ImageCenter),
        typeof(Point),
        typeof(LayerView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            new Point(-1, -1),
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            (o, a) => { (o as LayerView)?.OnImageCenterChanged(a); }));

private void OnImageCenterChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var bebCenter = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(this, ImageCenterProperty);
    var bebRect = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(this, ImageRectProperty);

    if (bebCenter != null && bebRect != null)
    {
        // Code here to 
        //   a) get the specific binding type and mode of each binding
        //   b) check to see if one of them is not readonly and if so...
        //   c) ... do what?  Throw an exception?
    }

}

public Point ImageCenter
{
    get => (Point)GetValue(ImageCenterProperty);
    set => SetValue(ImageCenterProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageRectProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ImageRect),
        typeof(Rect),
        typeof(LayerView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            Rect.Empty,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            (o, a) => { (o as LayerView)?.OnImageRectChanged(a); }));

private void OnImageRectChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var bebCenter = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(this, ImageCenterProperty);
    var bebRect = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(this, ImageRectProperty);

    if (bebCenter != null && bebRect != null)
    {
        // Code here to 
        //   a) get the specific binding type and mode of each binding
        //   b) check to see if one of them is not readonly and if so...
        //   c) ... do what?  Throw an exception?
    }

}

public Rect ImageRect
{
    get => (Rect)GetValue(ImageRectProperty);
    set => SetValue(ImageRectProperty, value);
}
```

Comment: `ValidateValueCallback` and `CoerceValueCallback` of a DP's `PropertyMetadata` and the `Register`, `RegisterAttached` methods are standard means WPF provides to control the valid value range of a DP.

Comment: `ValidateValueCallback` will not work for me.   Unlike the other callback functions, it does not give me the a reference to the control itself.  It assumes you can validate the value given only the value but I need to know if the control has bindings on the other property so I need the control.  `CoerceValueCallback` will not work because there is no way to coerce the setting properly.  I must disallow use of the control.

Comment: "*at least one of those bindings MUST use BindingMode.OneWayToSource*" - why exactly? If both properties are bound two-way, you just need to make sure not to cyclically update them.

Comment: As a note, using the `as` operator in the PropertyChangedCallback is pointless. The `o` argument is always a LayerView. If it happens not to be one, you would want to have an exception thrown instead of silently ignoring it. So better write `(o, a) => ((LayerView)o).OnImageRectChanged(a)`

Comment: For making sure that there are no call cycles, you will probably not even have to write any code. A PropertyChangedCallback is only called if a property has actually changed. If the ImageCenter callback sets ImageRect and that callback again sets ImageCenter, there should be no value change in ImageCenter and no further property update.

Comment: Yes, it might be that I just have to up my game on preventing the cyclical bindings.  I simplified this for purposes of the question, but the control has several other code paths (read: *`DependencyProperty` change handlers*) that internally set these values and I was not catching them all.  The only existing use case I have for the `ImageRect` property is a read-only one anyway but since I cannot bind to a view-model to a  ReadOnly `DependencyProperty`, I figured I would enforce the logic in the handlers.  I'll take a look at better handling the cyclical nature.  Thanks.

Comment: Good point on the `as` vs simple cast though.  I do want an exception there.  I just got into the habit and use it too many places.

Comment: FYI: Something I didn't realize but should have:  The argument to a `DependencyPropertyChangedCallback` function is always the registering control type (`LayerView` in my case), *except when the `DependencyProperty` uses inheritance*.  I started changing all my callbacks to use a simple cast, even for other properties.  Did it for a few attached ones that use the `Inherits` flag and suddenly started getting crashes.  Seems obvious in retrospect but there it is